# Django retrieve all rows from a table but the last three

Tags: python, django, database

I have the last three rows by using `Book.objects.order_by('-id')[:3]`, is there a way to get all the rows excluding those three elements?

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

```
Book.objects.order_by('-id')[3:]
```

if you want to get them in order

```
Book.objects.order_by('-id')[3:][::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have

```
books = Book.objects.order_by('-id')[:3]

list_to_exclude = [b.id for b in books]
```

and then

```
books_excl = Book.objects.all().exclude(id__in=list_to_exclude)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Book.objects.exclude(pk__in=Book.objects.order_by('-id')[:3])
```

Note: above query tested on postgres 9.5.3